# problem executing funcion infomap with weights in R

Tags: r

I have a object of type igraph created from this *dataset*
[complejolaribera.com/csv/ntw.csv](https://www.complejolaribera.com/csv/ntw.csv)
with this instruction

```
 g <- graph.data.frame(dataset, directed = FALSE)
```

I am trying to calculate the communities in graph **g** (currently the edges have no weights) 
If I calculate it without weights:

```
cluster_infomap(g)
```

it works correctly, but I need to calculate it with the edges weights,
for that I have a vector containing them (weights100, which has the same number of elements as the axes of ‘g’)  , These data are in 
https://www.complejolaribera.com/csv/whs.csv
Data in whs.csv are in the vector weigts100, then I run

```
 E(g)$weight <- weights100
```

This seems to assign the weights correctly, but once this is done it does not plot the graph :
plot(g)
Error in layout_with_fr(graph, dim = dim, ...) : 
And executing after including the weights

```
cluster_infomap(g)
```

the error is **“object cannot be coerced to type 'double'”**
Could someone explain to me how I can assign weights to g so that I can calculate the communities in a weightted network with the function  cluster_infomap() and others ?

Any help is more than welcome

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please could you format your code (you can use three backticks to start a code section). Could you share a sample of your data? It will help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in casa someone may need it...
It works if you pass th wheights like that

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(rede)
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value= rede$Peso)
g<-as.undirected(g)
```

and then applly the cluster_infomap function.